# CentOS 6 Squid Proxy error

Tags: proxy, squid, centos6

I am trying to install a Squid anonymous proxy on my home computer for a quick presentation tomorrow.
When I try to connect to it using Google Chrome, I get the following error code:

```
Error 130 (net:ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED)
```

I am able to see the Squid website from my computer however it gives an error message:

The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: /

```
    Invalid URL

Some aspect of the requested URL is incorrect.

Some possible problems are:

    Missing or incorrect access protocol (should be "http://" or similar)

    Missing hostname

    Illegal double-escape in the URL-Path

    Illegal character in hostname; underscores are not allowed.

Your cache administrator is root.
```

My conf file looks like:

```
#
# Recommended minimum configuration:
#
acl manager proto cache_object
#acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32 ::1
#acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8 0.0.0.0/32 ::1

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt to list your (internal) IP networks from where browsing
# should be allowed
#acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8    # RFC1918 possible internal network
#acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12 # RFC1918 possible internal network
#acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16        # RFC1918 possible internal network
#acl localnet src fc00::/7       # RFC 4193 local private network range
#acl localnet src fe80::/10      # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

#
# Recommended minimum Access Permission configuration:
#
# Only allow cachemgr access from localhost
#http_access allow manager localhost
#http_access deny manager

# Deny requests to certain unsafe ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports

# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

# We strongly recommend the following be uncommented to protect innocent
# web applications running on the proxy server who think the only
# one who can access services on "localhost" is a local user
#http_access deny to_localhost

#
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
#

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt localnet in the ACL section to list your (internal) IP networks
# from where browsing should be allowed
#http_access allow localnet
#http_access allow localhost

# And finally deny all other access to this proxy
http_access allow all

# Squid normally listens to port 3128
http_port 3128

# We recommend you to use at least the following line.
hierarchy_stoplist cgi-bin ?

# Uncomment and adjust the following to add a disk cache directory.
#cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 100 16 256

# Leave coredumps in the first cache dir
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid

# Add any of your own refresh_pattern entries above these.
refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%      1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%      0
refresh_pattern .               0       20%     4320
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to use squid in transparent proxying mode, you need to change the following line:

```
http_port 3128
```

to read:

```
http_port 3128 accel vhost allow-direct
```

For older versions of squid (I think before squid3), you can just write:

```
http_port 3128 transparent
```

Comment: tanx alot Khaled, more than 4 days i search about make squid transparent and all of websites and configuration that i tested is failed, its so simple solved just with added "accel vhost allow-direct" after port number. thanks again